# Remove spaces from a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How do you remove spaces from a string in VB.NET?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

2015: Newer LINQ & lambda.

1. As this is an old Q (and Answer), just thought to update it with
   newer 2015 methods.
2. The original "space" can refer to non-space whitespace (ie, tab, newline, paragraph separator, line feed, carriage return, etc,
   etc).
3. Also, Trim() only remove the spaces from the front/back of the string, it does not remove spaces inside the string; eg: " Leading and Trailing Spaces " will become "Leading and Trailing Spaces", but the spaces inside are still present.

---

```
Function RemoveWhitespace(fullString As String) As String
    Return New String(fullString.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray())
End Function
```

This will remove ALL (white)-space, leading, trailing and within the string.

Answer (score 90):

To remove ALL spaces:

```
 myString = myString.Replace(" ", "")
```

To remove leading *and* trailing spaces:

```
myString = myString.Trim()
```

Note: this removes any white space, so newlines, tabs, etc. would be removed.

Comment: .Trim removes white-space characters. Might not be what he wants.

Comment: Replace(" ", vbNullString) may run a hair faster, and (more importantly) be a bit clearer. YMMV.

Comment: I think vbNullstring is a hold over from pre .net days. `String.Empty` is maybe the more contemporary keyword.

Answer (score 18):

"Spaces" in the original post could refer to whitespace, and no answer yet shows how to remove ALL **whitespace** from a string. For that regular expressions are the most flexible approach I've found.

Below is a console application where you can see the difference between replacing just spaces or all whitespace.

You can find more about .NET regular expressions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module TestRegExp
    Sub Main()
        ' Use to match all whitespace (note the lowercase s matters)
        Dim regWhitespace As New Regex("\s")

        ' Use to match space characters only
        Dim regSpace As New Regex(" ")

        Dim testString As String = "First Line" + vbCrLf + _
        "Second line followed by 2 tabs" + vbTab + vbTab + _
        "End of tabs"

        Console.WriteLine("Test string :")
        Console.WriteLine(testString)

        Console.WriteLine("Replace all whitespace :")
        ' This prints the string on one line with no spacing at all
        Console.WriteLine(regWhitespace.Replace(testString, String.Empty))

        Console.WriteLine("Replace all spaces :")
        ' This removes spaces, but retains the tabs and new lines
        Console.WriteLine(regSpace.Replace(testString, String.Empty))

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 15):

To trim a string down so it does not contain two or more spaces in a row.  Every instance of 2 or more space will be trimmed down to 1 space.  A simple solution:

```
While ImageText1.Contains("  ")                     '2 spaces.
    ImageText1 = ImageText1.Replace("  ", " ")      'Replace with 1 space.
End While
```

Answer (score 5):

What about Regex.Replace solution?

```
myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, "\s", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

This will remove spaces only, matches the SQL functionality of rtrim(ltrim(myString))

```
Dim charstotrim() As Char = {" "c}
myString = myString .Trim(charstotrim)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a small function that will loop through and remove any spaces.

This is very clean and simple.

```
Public Shared Function RemoveXtraSpaces(strVal As String) As String
     Dim iCount As Integer = 1
     Dim sTempstrVal As String

     sTempstrVal = ""

     For iCount = 1 To Len(strVal)
        sTempstrVal = sTempstrVal + Mid(strVal, iCount, 1).Trim
     Next

     RemoveXtraSpaces = sTempstrVal

     Return RemoveXtraSpaces

End Function
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but that's completely overkill, and counterproductive.  You concatenate one character at a time, calling `Trim` every time?  Just use the accepted answer.

Comment: I would like to defend this answer as it provides a means to loop through the strings from one end or the other, to only remove a space in a given location within the string rather than all spaces. It may have value to someone looking to perform some clean up without taking out all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for to `trim` a `String`

```
Public Function AllTrim(ByVal GeVar As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim e As Integer
    Dim NewStr As String = ""
    e = Len(GeVar)
    For i = 1 To e
        If Mid(GeVar, i, 1) <> " " Then
            NewStr = NewStr + Mid(GeVar, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    AllTrim = NewStr
    ' MsgBox("alltrim = " & NewStr)
End Function
```